# Send and Receive SMS from my Website

Tags: web-development, web-services, sms

The way I plan to use it is:

1. Have people send SMS to a number to vote.
2. On the backend (assuming that the data comes back to my Web server), I will display the voting results on my Web site.
3. After say 10 minutes, I would like to press a button on my Web site so ONE of the people who sent an SMS earlier receive an SMS saying that person is a winner.

I'm an ASP .Net developer, so I just need an API to code against. One such company I saw that does this (but is limited to US) is:

- http://www.twilio.com/sms/

Do you know any international providers that are similar to Twilio SMS? I'm based in **Sydney, Australia**.

I've looked through the discussion here but could not find any International provider that does what Twilio SMS does:

- [How to add SMS text messaging functionality to my website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/533/how-to-add-sms-text-messaging-functionality-to-my-website)

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you create a new duplicate question instead of just adding information to the existing one?

Comment: I wasn't sure which Q&A forum is active.

Comment: This site isn't broken into forums, and when you edit a question, it gets put on the frontpage again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a google search, the exact phrase you will be looking for is "International SMS Gateway".

We also use twilio for a couple apps and have to say nothing beats their level of support and developer friendliness.  Also contact twilio for a reference.  I spoke with them once about SIP programming and they referred me to some great companies.

You can also try [cdyne's SMS service](http://www.cdyne.com/products/sms-notify.aspx).

Comment: http://www.cdyne.com/products/sms-notify.aspx

Comment: In the end it comes down to Twilio and Tropo. Tropo will expand to Australia soon with Australian numbers for two-way SMS. Meanwhile, I can live with Twilio's US number and that would cost senders more when they SMS to the US number.. probably a maximum of $0.55 per SMS?

Answer (score 1):

A provider supporting both [MO & MT messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_message#Text_Messaging_Gateway_Providers) (Mobile Originating and Terminating, respectively) is [Clickatell.](http://www.clickatell.com)  Based on your intentions, I believe you're looking for [long code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_number) support, which Clickatell definitely does.

Related reading that will assist:

- [Clickatell's API documentation](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/clickatell_api.php-), including HTTP/S, FTP, SMTP, etc.
- [Clickatell's "callback" functionality](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3anRu_lWdZS8sJ%3awww.clickatell.com/downloads/http/Clickatell_HTTP.pdf+callback&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgJH_c4EnDn3iCMh9ID1fqBzHXqhoLdYhIXv8nf9IJ_vZEBr7ia9MoS4hHu7Gm1I0AJf-FbyOGtZOsxHAVLkG3j_l34w6kpJv7PH-3TQOqb169yQv5BA2KBybXeLaoMGKknerUI&sig=AHIEtbT5XKCD8WJOSH0bm9RObD3UJrzyQw-), to speak back to your application/server
- [Wikipedia Long vs Short code comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_number#Long_Numbers_vs._Short_Codes), for those curious of the difference

And, of course, my inevitable disclaimer: I am currently employed by Clickatell.  Nevertheless (and perhaps directly because of my insight into the messaging engine), I wholeheartedly stand by my recommendation.

Comment: I'm having a look at SMSGlobal right now. Clickatell hasn't responded to my inquiry yet and it has been almost 24 hours!