# HTTP-to-SMS gateway software

Tags: php, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add SMS text messaging functionality to my website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/533/how-to-add-sms-text-messaging-functionality-to-my-website)

I want to send SMS via PHP or ASP API and want to process the incoming SMS; suggest me a good HTTP-to-SMS gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/) to send and receive SMS with PHP. Details are on their [SMS Gateway page](http://www.clickatell.com/products/sms_gateway.php).

Answer (score 0):

At work, my colleagues speak in good of [nexmo.com.](http://nexmo.com)