# How to confirm the Mobile Numbers of my users?

Tags: php, mysql, mobile, users

How can I confirm the Mobile Numbers of my users in order to reduce the number of scammers claiming to be in the US but who are actually in another country?

A free solution would be preferred.  I use PHP/MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send them a text message with a unique code and have them enter it into your website. No special software needed.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I send them a text message?  Preferably for free?

Comment: Check out this [question and answers](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/533/how-to-add-sms-text-messaging-functionality-to-my-website)